# A Save As Window pops up when I try to do things in outlook and word

Tags: microsoft-office-2003

Whenever I try to click a message in Outlook 2003 or do "New Message" I get a Save As file window and the program stops responding.

This also happens when I try to open Word files.

I've tried rebooting and I've tried to go through the repair process on the Office install disk.

Answer (score 0):

i suspect Word being the culprit.

i don't really have an answer, but see if Outtlook is 'behaving' better when you don't use Word as your email editor:

> Select **Tools** | **Options** from
>   the menu in Outlook.
>
> Click on the **Mail Format** tab.
>
> Clear the **Use Microsoft Office Word
>   2003 to edit e-mail messages**
>   checkbox..
>
> Close the dialog.

that's the good thing about Office 2003, Outlook users have a choice whether they want to use Word as editor or not. with Office 2007, this choice is gone. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with all microsoft office applications, with Outlook being the worst.  It turned out to be that my back-up drive has an "on-auto-off" switch that had accidentally been flipped to "auto".  Turned it back to "on" and have not had the problem since.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the normal.dot file for word in (XP) C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your F12 key is not depressed or slightly depressed.  This happened to me, and when I moved my keyboard everything was resolved.